# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Model>' to 'Model'

Tags: c#

I have an action result which I use to populate an IQueryable field and an IEnumerable field from my View Model. I can get one or the other to be populated, but not both at the same time as I run into this error. I need to populate both fields and then pass them to a view. Can anyone help me with this error?

View Model:

```
 public class AdminReviewViewModel {
    public IEnumerable<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    public IQueryable Clients { get; set; }

    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public int ReviewID {get; set;}
    public string ReviewName { get; set; }
    public int? ReviewPeriodID { get; set; }
    public string ReviewPeriodName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Review() {
            AdminReviewViewModel model = new AdminReviewViewModel();

            model.Clients = clientRepo.Clients;

            var reviews = reviewRepo.GetAllReviews();


            model = reviews.Select(s => new AdminReviewViewModel() {
                ClientID = s.ClientID,
                ReviewID = s.ReviewID,
                ReviewName = s.ReviewName,
                ReviewPeriodID = s.ReviewPeriodID,
                ReviewPeriodName = s.ReviewPeriod,
            });

            return View(model);
        }
```

View:

```
<div class="table table-responsive" id="TablePanel">
        <table class="table table-bordered"id="data">
            <thead class="TableHead">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Client ID
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Review ID
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Review Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Review Period ID
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Review Period Name
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach (var item in Model) {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClientID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReviewID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReviewName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReviewPeriodID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReviewPeriodName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Edit
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: this is not the relevant code, please show where you are using `Model`

Comment: Where do you get the exception (in which line)?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I receive the exception on this line:  model = model.Reviews.Select(s => new AdminReviewViewModel() {

Comment: @AndrewKilburn You get the exception because you try to overwrite a variable of type `AdminReviewViewModel` with an `IEnumerable<AdminReviewViewModel>` which comes from your linq statement.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Still no joy, unfortunately

Comment: What is the meaning of `model.Clients = clientRepo.Clients;`?

Comment: This calls the client repository to populate the client field in the ViewModel

Comment: What is your ReviewName when you have a collection of reviews?

Comment: @Oliver I have a collection of reviews and I'd like to append the variables from the ViewModel to the ones in the entities

Answer (score 2):

```
model = reviews.Select(s => new AdminReviewViewModel() {
            ClientID = s.ClientID,
            ReviewID = s.ReviewID,
            ReviewName = s.ReviewName,
            ReviewPeriodID = s.ReviewPeriodID,
            ReviewPeriodName = s.ReviewPeriod,
        });
```

Means "make `model` the result of calling `Select`". Since `model` is already defined as being a single `AdminReviewViewModel`, this doesn't make sense.

Likely you wanted this to be something more like:

```
public class AdminReviewViewModel
{
  public int ClientID { get; set; }
  public int ReviewID {get; set;}
  public string ReviewName { get; set; }
  public int? ReviewPeriodID { get; set; }
  public string ReviewPeriodName { get; set; }
}
public class AdminReviewListViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<Review> Reviews { get; set; } // Don't know what this is for, but leaving it.
  public IQueryable Clients { get; set; }
  public IQueryable<AdminReviewViewModel> ReviewList { get; set; }
}
public ActionResult Review()
{
  AdminReviewListViewModel model = new AdminReviewListViewModel();
  model.Clients = clientRepo.Clients;
  var reviews = reviewRepo.GetAllReviews();
  model.ReviewList = reviews.Select(s => new AdminReviewViewModel() {
    ClientID = s.ClientID,
    ReviewID = s.ReviewID,
    ReviewName = s.ReviewName,
    ReviewPeriodID = s.ReviewPeriodID,
    ReviewPeriodName = s.ReviewPeriod,
    });
  return View(model);
}
```

Then you have a model that contains the results you are selecting.

Comment: Why is `Review` of type `IEnumerable<Review>` and not `IEnumerable<AdminReviewViewModel>`?

Comment: Because Review is a separate entity.

Comment: Oh. I've got what you are trying to do.

Comment: Although I appreciate your willingness to help. It still returns the same error, I'm going to put Clients into a ViewBag now and make those into a select list and just return the reviews as a list. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think your `reviews` is some type of `IEnumerable<>` and you get with your linq Select a `IEnumerable<AdminReviewViewModel>`.

```
        model = reviews.Select(s => new AdminReviewViewModel() {
            ClientID = s.ClientID,
            ReviewID = s.ReviewID,
            ReviewName = s.ReviewName,
            ReviewPeriodID = s.ReviewPeriodID,
            ReviewPeriodName = s.ReviewPeriod,
        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

if you only need the first element, or you have to change the type of your model to `IEnumerable<AdminReviewViewModel>`.

**Update**

```
public ActionResult Review() {

    var reviews = reviewRepo.GetAllReviews();

    var models = reviews.Select(s => new AdminReviewViewModel() {
        ClientID = s.ClientID,
        ReviewID = s.ReviewID,
        ReviewName = s.ReviewName,
        ReviewPeriodID = s.ReviewPeriodID,
        ReviewPeriodName = s.ReviewPeriod,
        Clients = clientRepo.Clients
    });

    return View(models);
}
```

Comment: he is calling a "get all reviews" method, why would you think he is only trying to get one review?

Comment: Because of `AdminReviewViewModel model = new AdminReviewViewModel();`

Comment: @take Hi, Im not trying to return one review. I have called the model line multiple times when trying to return many results

Comment: @take Thanks for the updated answer. However, I can now only return the Reviews and not the Clients. I already did that previously

Comment: The clients are in the Models (`Clients = clientRepo.Clients`?)

Comment: Yes, the client is in the view model