# How to return LINQ result as a task

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a method:

```cs
public  Task<RequestPayinModel> InformationToSendPayInService(string qid)
{

 var payInObject = dbcontext.PayoutEntities.Where(s => s.QID == qid).Select(s => new RequestPayinModel
 {
      IBAN = s.IBAN,
      QID = s.QID,
      Rate = s.Rate,
      CollectionAmount = s.CollectionAmount,
      SettelmentAmount = s.SettelmentAmount,
      CollectionCurrency = s.CollectionCurrency,
      SettelmentCurrency = s.SettelmentCurrency
 });
  return  Task.FromResult(payInObject);
}
```

I get an error stating'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Linq.IQueryable<Core.Models.RequestPayinModel>>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Core.Models.RequestPayinModel>',any idea?

Comment: Currently `payInObject` represents your query and projection. Perhaps you want `payInObject.First();` to get the first result. Or `.FirstOrDefault();` if there can be zero results and you want to return `null` in that case rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: The error has little to do with tasks. Your syntax returns a single object and yet the query, even when it executes, returns a *list* of objects. As for tasks, you need to use `async/await` and one of the async EF Core operations like `ToListAsync`,  `SingleAsync`, `FirstAsync` etc to actually execute the query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Model>' to 'Model'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810768/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-linq-iqueryablemodel-to-model)

Comment: @Llama works!but why should i mention First?

Comment: Because the signature of your method implies you only want 1 result. `First` is the most logical, but some others could also be `Single` for example.

Comment: My Question is why is your method returning `Task<RequestPayinModel>` and not just `RequestPayinModel` if you're not using any async features?

Comment: @BarışCanYılmaz of course you can, thats what `Task.FromResult` is for.

Comment: @Jamiec that would be a very strong smell and a lie - the method says it's async when in reality it blocks. That's always an unpleasant surprise

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos indeed

Comment: Also note that there's very little benefit to returning an actual `Task`, for clarity I would just `await` the call inside the method. It's safer too as it means the caller won't dispose the DbContext before the task runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer, that actually executes the query asynchronously, is to use `SingleOrDefaultAsync` or `FirstOrDefaultAsync` :

```
public async Task<RequestPayinModel> InformationToSendPayInService(string qid)
{
    var payInObject = await dbcontext.PayoutEntities
                              .Where(s => s.QID == qid)
                              .Select(s => new RequestPayinModel
        {
            IBAN = s.IBAN,
            QID = s.QID,
            Rate = s.Rate,
            CollectionAmount = s.CollectionAmount,
            SettelmentAmount = s.SettelmentAmount,
            CollectionCurrency = s.CollectionCurrency,
            SettelmentCurrency = s.SettelmentCurrency
        })
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();


        return  payInObject;
}
```

It's a really bad idea to return a completed task to make a synchronous method look like an asynchronous one. Callers will expect the method to run without blocking and may end up with severely degraded performance or deadlocks if it actually blocks.

Returning `Task` doesn't make a method execute asynchronously. Neither does adding `async`. The method itself needs to execute an asynchronous operation.

`IQueryable<T>` is a query, not its results. We need to execute that query with `ToList`, `Single` etc or their asynchronous equivalents, `SingleAsync`, `FirstAsync` etc.

Using `await` allows awaiting an already active asynchronous operation without blocking a thread. Once that operation completes, execution resumes after the `await` expression.